# R match key values vector with irregular strings vector

Tags: r, parsing, vector, split

I'm stuck in a nightmare I have been trying to find in the forum without success. So I try my chance by asking directly.

I have a vector containing irregular strings with random cities and I am would like to extract/label each of this irregular strings from a key values vector containing the city names.
For example,

```
Vector <- c("...the life in Paris is ...","In Roma, there is...","...nice weekend in New York with...")
Cities <- c("London","Paris","Madrid","Roma","New York")
```

For each string in Vector, there should be a corresponding values from Cities to correspond.

I was thinking using loops at the beginning but the data size makes R search too long, I was more thinking of using a type of matricial calculation with grep but I always get errors.

Do you have an idea if this is the right way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` and `grepl`:

```
check_vec <- sapply(Cities, grepl, Vector)
row.names(check_vec) <- Vector

check_vec
#                                    London Paris Madrid  Roma New York
#...the life in Paris is ...          FALSE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE    FALSE
#In Roma, there is...                 FALSE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE    FALSE
#...nice weekend in New York with...  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE     TRUE
```

If you need the keyword for each vector:

```
apply(check_vec, 1, function (x) colnames(check_vec)[which(x)])
#        ...the life in Paris is ...                In Roma, there is... ...nice weekend in New York with... 
#                            "Paris"                              "Roma"                          "New York"
```

**edit**

For a safer way, as wisely advised by @nicola, you can use `vapply` instead of `sapply`:

```
check_vec <- vapply(Cities, grepl, x=Vector, logical(length(Vector)))
```

Comment: Nice. I'd encourage the use of `vapply` over `sapply`: `vapply(Cities, grepl, x=Vector,logical(length(Vector)))`.

Comment: thanks @nicola, I'm not used to vapply but it seems like I should ;-)

Comment: It looks great :). Unfortunately I have some unpredictable typos in Vector (for example Pris unstead of Paris) and when using the apply method, it squeezed out the rows that didn't find a match in the City vector. Is it possible to summarized in a single vector with the ones with match (your method is perfect) and the one that didn't (for further analysis).

P.S. Thank for the tip with vapply

Comment: hi @jernac, I don't really see what you mean, I tried a case with `Vector <- c(Vector, "I like Mdrid")` and got as result a list of 4 elements where the list one is named "I like Mdrid" and has value `character(0)`. You can further unlist this result but prior to that, you need to replace `character(0)` by `NA` (`unlist(lapply(apply(check_vec, 1, function (x) colnames(check_vec)[which(x)]), function(x) {if (!length(x)) x <- NA else x}))`)

Comment: Brillant, it works now. I have been too quick to unlist the result before replacing the character(0). Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using a text analysis package, **quanteda**.  It allows you to set up a set of pattern matches for city names, which is useful for instance if you have different spellings of cities (e.g. "Rome" and "Roma") but want to count them as a single city.  Below the matches use the simplified "glob" format, but you can also use regular expression matching.

```
require(quanteda)

# only required if you have compound word city names
compoundCities <- dictionary(list(NY = "New York"))
VectorPhrased <- phrasetotoken(Vector, compoundCities)

# uses the "glob" format for Pattern Matching
citiesDict <- dictionary(list(London = c("London", "Londres"), Paris = "Paris", 
                              Rome = "Rom?", NewYork = "New_York"))

dfm(VectorPhrased, dictionary = citiesDict, verbose = FALSE)
# Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 4 features.
# 3 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#        features
# docs    London Paris Rome NewYork
#   text1      0     1    0       0
#   text2      0     0    1       0
#   text3      0     0    0       1
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my side. To avoid compound names, I use tolower and delete all spaces to have clean and neat string (for example thelifeinparisis). Then I constitutes the dictionary with the cities in lower letters. Can the real value of text1 be displayed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there, since it's not part of your example. But if you change `valuetype = "regex"`then you will be able to find matches for say "paris" even within strings like "thelifeinparis". But if you expand the example I can address it directly.

Comment: Great, it works (nice package by the way). It was my fault not having clearly explicit the whole process behind the example. I see that value type take 3 arguments (glob, regex and fixed). I don't understand the glob format ("glob"-style wildcard), how different it is from regex (both are used for pattern matching)?